# How to exclude access to new subclasses while still allowing testing from another assembly?

Tags: c#, interface, integration-testing, .net-assembly, encapsulation

I encountered a situation which I'm not sure is possible in C#, but thought I'd ask anyway. I have a need to expose a type from a class library that has two concrete subclasses, and I don't want users to be able to create new instances of the subclass - however if I make everything internal then users won't be able to create instances for testing purposes.

What I have currently is something like this (all examples simplified, but get across the idea):

```
public abstract class Result
{
    internal Result() { }
}

internal class SuccessResult : Result { }

internal class FailureResult<TError> : Result
{
    TError Error { get; init; }
}
```

The users of the library would have access to a pair of interfaces like the following, with one of the interfaces supplied at a time, thus restricting the types of result that can be created:

```
public interface IPartialResultFactory
{
    Result Success();
}

public interface IResultFactory : IPartialResultFactory
{
    Result Error<TError>(TError error);
}
```

Doing the above I can ensure that only code with access to that assembly's internal classes can create new subtypes of `Result`, however when someone would be testing their integration with the library, they wouldn't be able to test the code easily as they can't create new instances of the `Result` class.

The solution I'm currently working with is to redefine the `Result` class as follows:

```
public abstract class Result
{
    internal Result() { }

    public static Result Success() => new SuccessResult();

    public static Result Error<TError>(TError error) => new ErrorResult<TError>(error);
}
```

However this has two issues:

- First it introduces coupling between `Result` and it's subclasses that I'd like to avoid if possible in case I want to add other subclasses at a future point in time;
- Second it means in a case where a user would be provided an `IPartialResultFactory` instance they could still return an `ErrorResult` instance where I would like to restrict them to only returning a `SuccessResult`.

So, to summarise, is there a way I could allow a user to test integration with my code, creating instances of `Result`, but then providing restrictions to how those instances can be created for the actual integration?

Comment: Are you trying to create something like a algebraic data type?

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand: you want internal subclasses but allow to get instances of them from another assembly for testing purposes? It seems to me that this is not possible, precisely because of the restriction due to the level of encapsulation, which is internal here... thus you can't get code that compiles, even using interfaces, unless maybe bypassing the constraints of OOP logic by using reflection or IL code injection. Just saying, I've never set foot in this kind of thing. You need to provide a testing public connector between the tester and these classes.

Comment: @Sweeper to a certain extent yes, but also no. Internally I'm converting the instances of `Result` to a simple internal implementation of a OneOf monad (similar to a disjoint union), however the intent is for the exposed part to be as idiomatic as possible, and using a OneOf monad here would already be messy due to nested generics, and I want the possibility of adding more `Result`s without breaking existing usages.

Comment: @Olivier Rogier I think I agree that I don't think this is possible as, at least not without some really funky coffee weirdness. Your point about a testing connector is interesting, I'm not sure this will ever get released as a NuGet package, but it might be an idea to add a second package for testing it that allows a way to construct `Result` instances. If someone wants to go out of their way to use a package marked as test only in non test code, then that's on them.

Comment: Is there a reason as to why you're not exposing an interface types for your Result classes?

Comment: @ChrisBD because in wanting to control when a user of the framework can return a success result or one of with success or error results. If I simply exposed an interface there is nothing stopping the user returning an error result when only success results are supported. Additionally while the internal properties etc... of these example results above are fairly similar the internals of my actual classes aren't compatible, so any interface would have to define properties for both, but only use stone of them each implementation, which is really quite code smelly.

Comment: Aren't you already allowing the user to determine which Result they want by allowing them to call the factory classes to generate them?

There must be some common interface between the Result classes, as I don't see how the user will access the TError property of FailureResult as its internal to your library.

Comment: The user won't, and shouldn't access the `TError` property, that's for the implementor to provide and the library to handle. Essentially the user shouldn't need to worry about any of the implementation details of `Result`, simply that calling either `Success` or `Failure` on the interfaces will return the correct implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the unit tests are within the same solution then you can edit the project file for the project that contains your Result class and add the following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute">
      <_Parameter1>ResultImplementationTests</_Parameter1>
    </AssemblyAttribute>
  </ItemGroup>
```

where `ResultImplementationTests` is the name of the Unit test project that will be testing your Result class.

Comment: I assume OP can't know in advance all possible client test project names, so this will not work.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly it. The idea is this weighs be a framework/library that could be imported and implemented arbitrarily, so I won't know what assemblies to expose it's internals to ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure about your use of public factory interfaces to create your Result classes, but would something like this work.

I've found that its often best to provide firm interface definitions rather than class types with populated methods - remember that a completely abstract class is the same as an interface.

With interface types the library users can easily produce their own unit tests that use Mock implementations of them.

I have two types of `Result` that I wish to make available, each defined by the following interfaces:

```
public interface IResultBase
{
    SupportedResultType Type { get; }
    IResult Result { get; }
}

public interface IResultComplex : IResultBase
{
    IError Error { get; }
}
```

Where

```
public enum SupportedResultType
{
    Base,
    Complex
}
```

The data that I wish to give to transfer within my `Result` types:

```
public interface IResult
{
    string SomeValue { get;  }
    bool Success { get;  }
}

public class Result : IResult
{
    public Result(string someValue, bool success)
    {
        SomeValue = someValue;
        Success = success;
    }
    public string SomeValue { get; }
    public bool Success { get; }
}

public interface IError
{
    string ErrorMessage { get; }
}

public class Error : IError
{
    public Error(string errorMessage)
    {
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; }
}
```

As long as the interface type is observed it doesn't matter what the concrete class is behind it and the users of your code library can still use them.

Here's an example of what I mean.

I create them with a factory, but in reality your library users could use a public method that returns the concrete implementations.

```
public sealed class ResultFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<SupportedResultType, IResultLocator> _resultLocators;

    private ResultFactory()
    {
        _resultLocators = new Dictionary<SupportedResultType, IResultLocator>();

        foreach (SupportedResultType resultType in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(SupportedResultType)))
        {
            IResultLocator creator;
            switch (resultType)
            {
                case SupportedResultType.Base:
                    creator = new ResultBaseLocator();
                    break;

                case SupportedResultType.Complex:
                    creator = new ResultComplexLocator();
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }

            _resultLocators.Add(resultType, creator);

        }
    }

    private static readonly Lazy<ResultFactory> LazyInstantiation =
        new Lazy<ResultFactory>(() => new ResultFactory());

    public static ResultFactory Initialise() => LazyInstantiation.Value;

    public IResultBase Create(SupportedResultType resultType) =>
        _resultLocators[resultType].Get();

}
```

The factory doesn't actually create the concrete instance, this is performed by an `IResultLocator` instance, which allows us to expand the number of variations of `IResultBase` or `IResultCompex` instances at a later date whilst minimising the changes to the factory.

```
internal class ResultBaseLocator : IResultLocator
{
    public IResultBase Get()
    {
        return new ResultBase();
    }
}

internal class ResultComplexLocator : IResultLocator
{
    public IResultBase Get()
    {
        return new ResultComplex();
    }
}
```

For my example here are the concrete implementations:

```
internal class ResultBase : IResultBase
{
    public SupportedResultType Type { get; } = SupportedResultType.Base;
    public IResult Result { get; } = new Result("ResultBase", true);
}

internal class ResultComplex : IResultComplex
{
    public SupportedResultType Type { get; } = SupportedResultType.Complex;
    public IResult Result { get; } = new Result("ResultComplex", false );
    public IError Error { get; } = new Error("Error message");
}
```

The above classes I placed into a class library and then I created a console application that referenced it. The following code, within the console application, demonstrates them.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (SupportedResultType resultType in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(SupportedResultType)))
        {
            IResultBase result = ResultFactory.Initialise().Create(resultType);
            Console.WriteLine($"Result is type {result.Type}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Result.SomeValue = {result.Result.SomeValue}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Result.Success = {result.Result.Success}");

            if (result.Type == SupportedResultType.Complex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Result.Error.ErrorMessage = {((IResultComplex)result).Error.ErrorMessage}");
            }
           
            if (result.GetType().GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IResultComplex)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Result is IResultComplex type");
            }

        }
    }
```

The output appears as follows:

[image]

Comment: Normally I would completely agree with you, however the end result I'm looking for doesn't really lend itself towards this implementation. The intent is to have implementors implement an interface (as part of a framework) that will be provided either `IPartialResultFacory` (as they're only allowed to return `SuccessResult` instances), or `IResultFactory` instances. Using your suggested implementation a user could return an arbitrary instance with either `Success == true` or `Success == false` at any point, which should be prevented behaviour within the framework.

Comment: Additionally while a fully abstract abstract class is very similar to an interface they are subtly distinct in C#. First you can make all of it's constructors `internal` which would mean a subclasses from outside the same assembly are impossible, additionally you can define things like private/protected methods (which given some of the latest C# interface features is actually much less applicable).